# Indexing same URL in desktop and Smartphone for different Domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mobile

I created a mobile version for my website www.m.example.com. I put all my mobile code in directory named "mobile" I put a code in htaccess for redirecting mobile vs desktop. How can I Index in google www.example.com for both www.example.com and for www.m.example.com. I want to block indexing subdomain page directly in google mobile version.

I blocked directory "mobile" from indexing using robots.text. But my problem is that when i searched in smartphone, URL and title displayed correctly, But snippet shows "the discription of this item not available because of robots.text".

What is want is I have www.example.com/category also www.m.example.com/category. I want to index www.example.com/category page only. Block www.m.example.com/category from indexing. Also the snippet should be right.

Now I use `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />` in mobile pages. Is there any hope?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the Google Webmasters Tools/Google Search Console

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

You declare the websites that you own and manage, and then you can hide or hilight the webpages or subdomains that you want.
You can hide every m.example.com for example.

Good luck